# Use of as much as

Tags: usage

> Thief stole  as much money as all money I had

When I turn this sentence into passive voice Would it be correct to say;

> Money half as much as all money I had was stolen by thief.

Does “Money half as much as all money” means the same ”as much money as all money ” ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Money half as much as all money* is not English, I'm afraid.

We generally use *as much as* when we are comparing two separate things, not when talking about part of the same whole, so

> *The thief stole half [of] the money I had.*

is the normal way to say what you are trying to say.

You can use *half as much as* when you are comparing with a different sum of money:

> *I've collected half as much money as you have in your account.*
>
> *I've got half as much money as I need for this holiday.*

To turn the first sentence passive,

> *Half the money I had was stolen [by a thief].*

Comment: If I say “money half as much as you have in your account was collected” based on your sentence I've collected half as much money as you have in your account.

Comment: "Half as much money as you have in your account" would be a more normal order, @Foreignstudent

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But I wonder if “money half as much as you have in your account was collected”   would be correcet grammatically.

Comment: I don't think it is grammatical, @Foreignstudent, but I'm not certain. There may be circumstances where it is possible, but I can't think of any. Either _Half as much money as you have in your account was collected_, or more commonly _Half as much money was collected as you have in your account_.